# Availability of ROR flash functionality in ASP.Net-mvc

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

Does Microsoft MVC make available a mechanism comparable to RubyOnRails internal storage container known as flash? The preference would be not using UpdatePanel tricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the TempData object.

Comment: The answer is correct, but do note that TempData is for redirects only. Use ViewData when not redirecting.

Comment: Right, TempData lasts for one trip back and forth after that it is wiped out.  It also relies on cookies.  Om nom nom

Comment: I use TempData always and just clear it after it is used. THat way I don't have to use a different mechanism for redirects/views.